# Html.Raw(string unicode)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I create a variable with unicode characters like "tümü" in `javascript` but it looks like below:

```
var tÃ¼mÃ¼ = "tÃ¼mÃ¼";  //true form : var tümü = "tümü"
    if ("@Culture" == "tr-TR") {

        @Html.Raw("$('#citySelect [value=-1]').text('Tümü')"); //string seem on page:tÃ¼mÃ¼  how can I fix this ??
    } 
    else {
        $("#citySelect [value='-1']").text("All");
    }
```

Comment: When I do this: @Html.Raw("Tümü") It outputs Tümü properly. Does it do that for you? Is your character set utf-8?

Comment: Is second line really working:

 if ("@Culture" == "tr-TR")

I see that @Culture is in quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to the character encoding on your page. Add the following in the `<head>` tag before anything else.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```